# Rounded corner combobox connected with combobox item in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, rounded-corners

I tried to modify the template and here's what I can do

[image: what I can do]

I can make the lower part of combobox rounded, but the upper part needs to link with the button like picture bellow

[image: what I want]

Is there any way to do it in XAML only?

Comment: It's not an answer, but as a graphic idea I would make round only the top left and top right corner, leaving the bottom left and bottom right with angles.

Comment: @FrancescoB. it looks pretty weird if item list is not open. Also this is the design from my customer